# Maximum CAShapeLayer size?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, ios, cashapelayer

I'm trying to draw a semi-transparent shape over an image.

I've got a `UIView` which has it's layer's contents set to the image, with a `CAShapeLayer` sub-layer who's path is set to the shape. There are a few of these `UIViews` inside a parent `UIView`, which is the zoom child of a `UIScrollView`.

Everything is fine on the iPhone, but when I zoom in on the iPad, the `UIViews` get quite large, and the `CAShapeLayers` disappear. The images display fine though. I guessed that the problem was a size issue, so I split the `CAShapeLayers` in two, so that there was a left and a right side. Now, they both get shown unless the user zooms in really far, for example while "un-pinching" beyond my maximum zoom, just before they bounce back.

Splitting up my `CAShapeLayers` further is doable, but a little fiddly. So, I've got a couple of questions:

1. Is there a maximum size constraint for `CAShapeLayers`? Why does it not apply to the layer's image contents?
2. Why are the `CAShapeLayers` re-drawing during a zoom pinch inside a `UIScrollView`? Shouldn't the whole zoom view (the `UIScrollView's` immediate child) be rasterized during the inch? How can I make it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the maximum area on my computer (a 2006 MacBook) is 1024*1024.

A full screen shape on the iPad is 1004 pixels heigh, giving a maximum width of about 1044 pixels, for example if you want a large shape in a horizontal scroll view.

When pinch bounce zooming, the actual height of the shape gets larger, pushing the maximum width down to about 250 pixels. This is narrower than I'd like, but doable.

*This might be different on a physical iPad, but these are the limits in the simulator on my dev box.*

Comment: I believe there's no limit for the CAShapeLayer on the iPad device, but there's a 1024 x 1024 limit in simulator. I'm actually using 2048 x 2048 in iPad 3.2 and it works great. I just spent 2 hours of my day trying to fix a problem that I didn't have, just because I hadn't check it on iPad device yet. Your note saved me a lot of time. I was planning to modify the script to limit the shape to 1024 x 1024.